# What is the bug in this program?

Tags: java, sockets

Very new to Java. My guess is it should be `new Socket ("nothing",8)`?

```
public static void test(String s[]) {
  try {
    echoSocket = new Socket("nothing", 7);
    out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host: .");
    return;
  }
  process(out, in, echoSocket);
  out.close();
  in.close();
  echoSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: On SO, you post your Bug and ask for solution. Not just post your code and surprise us by asking what's the bug.

Comment: @RohitJain, I want to show I did put some effort from my side.

Comment: Yeah that's right, and I really appreciate that, but you should also post what is the exact problem you are facing, so that the problem can be solved more quickly. Like in case of any Exception, a `StackTrace` is so much helpful. Else it will only take more time.

Comment: @RohitJain, as I said, very new to Java  Therefore was taking some online quizzes to improve my skill. Some of them I was able to solve. Some of them could not. The quiz just asks you these questions, point blank. No history/context.

Comment: @Reimeus codereview is for code that works as expected, but improvements can be made and potential pitfalls identified. If a bug is known to exist, SO is the place for it. Not that this is a good example of how to ask it... but this is the right place for this sort of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. From the [Java docs on Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), if your server is nothing, and your port is 8, you are correct. But not knowing what you are trying to connect to, it's impossible to debug this code.

Answer (score 1):

The Constructor of Socket with a String and an Int asks for the hostname and the port. The host "nothing" is not a valid hostname. This might cause your "bug".

Answer (score 1):

Still you can try with "nothing" if your host file has a ip maping for this "nothing" port 7 is runing on it.

part of host file

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       192.168.2.23
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       nothing
```

in this case your "nothing" is localhost